# Unable to get all characters from serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm doing a keypad project for 10-digit ID input. For each key press, it will send '1' or '2' or '3' and so on to the serial port. However, after trying to display the content of my id buffer with `Console.WriteLine(id[i])`, it only display the first keypad value from serial port. I need to display all 10-digit input from the buffer. I cant find where is the error in the code. I'm using `System.IO.Ports`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char[] id = new char[10] ;

    SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

    port.Open();

    if (port.IsOpen) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("port is now open");       
    } 
    else 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("port not opened correctly"); 
    }

    port.Read(id, 0, 10); 

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(id[i]);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: looks good so far. are you sure there is actually data to read? I usually bind the reading process to the `SerialPort`s `DataReceived`-event. Also, you say you believe, but did you actually debug?

Comment: You should add your sending code as well. Maybe the problem is on the sending side? You should also set the timeout for your Read operation as shown here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timeoutexception(v=vs.110).aspx to a large value in order to wait for data to arrive.

Comment: Standard bug, you cannot ignore the return value of Read().  It will only ever be 10 when you have a really, really slow machine.  You have to keep calling Read() until you have them all.

Comment: Ok I finally managed to sort it through. I refer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340513/serialport-read-does-not-respect-readtimeout][1]

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant for pointing that out. I will never know it is a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check whether your device is sending any data.
You can use a RS232 terminal for this.

[Termite](http://www.compuphase.com/software_termite.htm#_) is a free terminal software.

If your hardware is sending data correctly,

Add [DataReceive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event,

```
port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
```

Then use ReadExisting() method for capture received data.

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   Console.WriteLine(port.ReadExisting());
}
```

Comment: I actually not too familiar with ReadExisting() method. Does it stores all the characters received in an array?

Comment: No. it returns a string. You can find more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: All right thanks!. I'm using `DataReceivedHandler` and it works. :))